# React Custom Component Parameter Is Not Defined

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-typescript, react-tsx

I'm currently using the Typescript version of reactjs and keep getting the error "message is not defined".

This error is coming from line 5.

```js
import './App.css'
import * as React from "react";

const MyComponent: React.FC = ({ message: string }) => {
    return <h1>{message}</h1>
}

export default function App() {
  return (
      <div className="app">
        <MyComponent message="hello world"></MyComponent>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Comment: Your syntax is wrong: `({ message: string })` doesn't do what you think it does. You probably want `({ message }: { message: string })`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may have to typecheck your component so it knows to expect message as a parameter! Please see the following post for some more context: https://fettblog.eu/typescript-react/components/. Here is a quick solution that might help!

```
import './App.css'
import * as React from "react";

type MyComponentProps = {
  message: string
}

const MyComponent: React.FC = ({ message }: MyComponentProps) => {
    return <h1>{message}</h1>
}
```

Comment: Ah, thank you! For some odd reason I googled this but couldn't find the answer for this, it works now.

Comment: Yay, sounds good. I'm glad it works! Best of luck with your app.